# Why can't my application find a dependent dll in the same directory?

Tags: c#, interop, c++-cli, dll

I have a simple console test application, `ConsoleApplication1.exe`, which references another assembly `clipper.dll`.

On 3 machines that I've tested it on, it is possible to place both files in e.g. `c:\test\`, and execute `ConsoleApplication1.exe`.

On one other machine, which happens to be a client machine, running `ConsoleApplication1.exe` results in a program crash and the following being printed to the console:

```
C:\test>dir
 Volume in drive C has no label.
 Volume Serial Number is 7C46-414F

 Directory of C:\test

07/12/2010  06:08 PM    <DIR>          .
07/12/2010  06:08 PM    <DIR>          ..
07/12/2010  05:13 PM            11,776 ClassLibrary1.dll
07/12/2010  05:13 PM            30,208 ClassLibrary1.pdb
07/12/2010  04:55 PM             3,572 ClassLibrary1.tlb
19/11/2010  02:46 PM           235,008 clipper.dll
19/11/2010  02:46 PM         1,534,976 clipper.pdb
07/12/2010  05:13 PM             6,144 ConsoleApplication1.exe
07/12/2010  05:13 PM            11,776 ConsoleApplication1.pdb
01/08/2010  12:52 PM           139,264 nunit.core.dll
01/08/2010  06:41 AM            57,344 nunit.core.interfaces.dll
01/08/2010  06:41 AM           135,168 nunit.framework.dll
01/08/2010  06:41 AM           547,262 nunit.framework.xml
              11 File(s)      2,712,498 bytes
               2 Dir(s)  477,821,784,064 bytes free

C:\test>ConsoleApplication1.exe

Unhandled Exception: System.IO.FileNotFoundException: Could not load file or ass
embly 'clipper.dll' or one of its dependencies. The specified module could not b
e found.
   at ConsoleApplication1.Program.Main(String[] args)
```

This is a odd to me, although I don't understand dll load rules comprehensively I thought it would search the CWD for the specified file. And the fact this same setup works on the various other computers I've tried is also odd.

Curiously, on a working computer if I remove clipper.dll and then run it:

```
C:\Temp>ConsoleApplication1.exe

Unhandled Exception: System.IO.FileNotFoundException: Could not load file or ass
embly 'clipper, Version=1.0.3975.26584, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null' or
 one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified.
   at ConsoleApplication1.Program.Main(String[] args)
```

The unhandled exception is slightly different, with a full assembly name.

- Both `ConsoleApplication1.exe` and `clipper.dll` are built for .NET 4.
- All machines have the .NET 4 runtime installed. The problem machine does not have the .NET sdk
- clipper.dll is a combination of ummanaged c++ code and C++/CLI. It is a suspicious character because it is basically the first C++/CLI .NET assembly I have created and much fumbling was involved. It seems to load in reflector fine.
- These efforts came about when I was trying to figure out why I was unable to successfully utilise a COM object (call it `foo.dll`) which also referenced `clipper.dll` - all also on the same problem machine. After several hours of regasm hell I was able to further isolate it to this.

Comment: also remove pdbs from the installation folder

Answer (score 13, accepted):

> or one of its dependencies

Did you deploy the [CRT runtime DLLs](http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/en/details.aspx?FamilyID=a7b7a05e-6de6-4d3a-a423-37bf0912db84&displaylang=en) on that machine?  Make sure to deploy the Release build of your assembly.  The debug version of the CRT is not redistributable.

Comment: I don't understand 'redistributable'. Microsoft often uses the term in their download page. What is it? What's the difference 'redistributable package' and 'non-redistributable package'. Give me a hint please.

Comment: @Ben - you cannot give a copy of a file that has a Microsoft copyright to somebody else unless Microsoft gives you permission to do so.  The redist.txt file in the VS install directory lists the files you can redistribute.

Comment: Thanks Hans. Had checked for the presence of CRT, but did not realise (or even think about) the debug version causing problem.s

Answer (score 2):

I don't know why it happed to u, but if you will copy the dll to system32 directory it will lead to 2 option
1) It will work
2) It won't work and that way you will know it doesn't relate to the dll path

Answer (score 1):

Make sure to include the C++ runtime Libraries ([CRT](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/abx4dbyh%28v=VS.90%29.aspx)) on your client machine.

Answer (score 0):

Well , there may be lot of reasons

> These efforts came about when I was trying to figure out why I was unable to successfully utilise a COM object (call it foo.dll) which also referenced clipper.dll - all also on the same problem machine. After several hours of regasm hell I was able to further isolate it to this.

is the COM object (foo.dll) registered on the troubled computer?

Please remove pdbs from the installation folder also.

Answer (score 0):

Are your application files downloaded from the internet? I once had the same problem where my program was downloaded in a zip file, and then extracted on the client machine. Once extracted I was getting exactly the same error message "The specified module could not b
e found."

It turned out to be Windows security policy for files downloaded from the internet. Windows will "block" downloaded files, and they need to be unblocked manually. In my case, I needed to right click on the file, select properties and then select "unblock", my application was then able to load the assembly as normal.

http://i3.codeplex.com/Project/Download/FileDownload.aspx?ProjectName=mpe&DownloadId=163767

Alternatively you can unblock the zip file before extracting it, and then all extracted files will also be unblocked.